# Coroutines vs. async-await

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created the [coroutines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coroutines) tag. However, I then noticed that there is already the [async-await](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/async-await) tag. I think these are distinct concepts, even though in some languages, that distinction is a bit blurry. I would argue that coroutines are not necessarily asynchronous. However, if the consensus is that they are just synonyms, then perhaps one should be made a synonym of the other (or just removed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) and [async/await](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Async/await) *are not the same*.

Coroutines are a control flow mechanism. You can reimplement coroutines by using `goto` and mutating an address both sides have access to. As such a coroutine is to `goto`, what `for` loops are to `while` loops. A form of sugar.

Async/await *requires* arbitrary suspension and resumption of functions so builds off of coroutines. As `goto` would be horrible to work with. However the async/await pattern specializes coroutines with a scheduler to manage the coroutines.

You can build your own async/await scheduler in any language which supports coroutines (not [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)), which only support unidirectional communication). Which is how Python had support for the async/await pattern way before `async` and `await` were added to the language.

---

> in some languages, that distinction is a bit blurry.

If the only coroutines the language supports are async/await ones then users likely can conflate the two concepts.

> coroutines are not necessarily asynchronous

Coroutines have nothing to do with asynchronous. Asynchronous (async/await) requires* coroutines to work.

<sup>*: T&C apply</sup>

> if the consensus is that they are just synonyms, then perhaps one should be made a synonym of the other (or just removed)?

The two terms are not synonymous. As such the [coroutine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coroutine) tag shouldn't be removed because of such a train of thought.